# create 1 daily calendar event with multiple times a day

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to create custom calendar events for iOS, and have succeeded in obtaining one `eventIdentifier` for weekly, monthly and yearly events using:

```
initRecurrenceWithFrequency:
interval:
daysOfTheWeek:
daysOfTheMonth:
monthsOfTheYear:
weeksOfTheYear:
daysOfTheYear:
setPositions:
end:
```

now i want to do the same for daily events.

for example i want one daily event (eventIdentifier)  from:
**6AM -> 8AM** and **2PM -> 5PM** and **9PM -> 11PM**

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't work on iOS, I created multiple events on the same day